# Windows Autostart App Not Running Anymore

Tags: windows-10, openvpn, runas, autostart

I'm not sure if it is due to the latest Windows 10 update or something else. But recently, OpenVPN won't start up automatically anymore. Even though it is placed in the user autostart folder for the start menu.

Any advice on how to trouble shoot this?

[image]

Comment: What I did also was adding a new user account to this PC, so that might have had an influence as well

Comment: on the icon I see an UAC shield, so the app requires admin permissions and such applciation were never automatically started since Vista when UAC was added. Use [task scheduler](https://superuser.com/a/537101/174557) to run programs at login.